# Symfony: In my "add" controller, how can I make this associated entity get updated?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I have 2 entities: Article and Author. Here's my "add" controller for ArticleController.php. I'm trying to see if the author exists (based on email). If he does exist, I'd like to grab the new first/last name and update the existing entry. If he doesn't exist then I'd like to add the new one it.

New Authors get added just fine if I remove my "if" and setAuthor line. I can't get the names of existing Authors to get updated as I'd expect though!

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $article = new article();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\articleType', $article);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        // check to see if the email already exists.
        $existingAuthor = $em
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Author')
            ->findOneByEmail($article->getAuthor()->getEmail());

        if ($existingAuthor) {

            //if the email does exist, grab the incoming name and update the existing name with it.
            $existingAuthor->setFirstName($article->getAuthor()->getFirstName());
            $existingAuthor->setLastName($article->getAuthor()->getLastName());
            $author = $existingAuthor;

        } else {
            //Other wise it's a new author. Set the creation timestamp.
            $date = new \DateTime("now");
            $article->getAuthor()->setCreatedDate($date);
        }

        $article->setAuthor($author);

        //Set Created Date
        $date = new \DateTime("now");
        $article->setCreatedDate($date);

        //Persist to database.

        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush($article);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('article_show', array('id' => $article->getId()));

    }

    return $this->render('article/new.html.twig', array(
        'article' => $article,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**Here's the Article entity**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"name"}, message="Note: That article already existed.")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="thumbnail", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $thumbnail;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Author", inversedBy="articles", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $author;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Review", mappedBy="article")
     */
    private $reviews;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->reviews = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set thumbnail
     *
     * @param string $thumbnail
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setThumbnail($thumbnail)
    {
        $this->thumbnail = $thumbnail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get thumbnail
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getThumbnail()
    {
        return $this->thumbnail;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdDate
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setCreatedDate($createdDate)
    {
        $this->createdDate = $createdDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedDate()
    {
        return $this->createdDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set authorId
     *
     * @param integer $authorId
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setAuthorId($authorId)
    {
        $this->authorId = $authorId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get authorId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAuthorId()
    {
        return $this->authorId;
    }

    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Author $author
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setAuthor(\AppBundle\Entity\Author $author = null)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Author
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    /**
     * Add review
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Review $review
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function addReview(\AppBundle\Entity\Review $review)
    {
        $this->reviews[] = $review;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove review
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Review $review
     */
    public function removeReview(\AppBundle\Entity\Review $review)
    {
        $this->reviews->removeElement($review);
    }

    /**
     * Get reviews
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getReviews()
    {
        return $this->reviews;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

Here's the form:

[image: The form]

Thanks in advance for any response. Oh, also, is this an acceptable place for such logic? I'm going to move the if into a helper class to be used in other controllers ... but is a controller a good spot for calling this logic even?

**UPDATE: Based on sakhunzai's answer this is currently working. These are 2 methods in my article controller.**

But I still have some questions regarding best practices. IF anyone can answer those (in a comment on sakhunzai's answer) I'd be very grateful!

```
   protected function getAuthor(\AppBundle\Entity\Author $author){

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $email = $author->getEmail();

        $existingAuthor = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Author')->findOneByEmail($email);

        if($existingAuthor){
            $existingAuthor->setFirstName($author->getFirstName());
            $existingAuthor->setLastName($author->getLastName());
            $author = $existingAuthor;
        } else {
            $date = new \DateTime("now");
            $author->setCreatedDate($date);
            $em->persist($author);
        }

        $em->flush();

        return $author;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new article entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="article_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $article = new Article();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ArticleType', $article);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


            //Update existing author or create new
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $author = $this->getAuthor($article->getAuthor());
            //Set the author
            $article = $form->getData();
            $article->setAuthor($author);
            //Set Created Date
            $date = new \DateTime("now");
            $article->setCreatedDate($date);
            $em->persist($article);
            $em->flush($article);




            return $this->redirectToRoute('article_show', array('id' => $article->getId()));

        }

        return $this->render('article/new.html.twig', array(
            'article' => $article,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

Comment: the line `->findOneByEmail($article->getAuthor()->getEmail());` seem ambiguous. The first line of you function is creating new Article and I suspect it has not bee assigned a Author yet , which means the above line where you are trying to `getAuthor()` will return null.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You're correct that it'll return NULL but only if the email address ($article->getAuthor()->getEmail()) being submitted doesn't exist...

$article->getAuthor() returns the perfect data right before the article persist... the author that's set at $article->setAuthor($author) just isn't updated. Am I misunderstanding how persist works? I thought it'd updated this related data. IF not, what's the best way to handle that? Thank you!

Comment: if the Author is a valid author you dont need to update it again by `$article->setAuthor($author);` . But what I suspect is that you are trying to create `Article` and `Author` in one go. Please add screenshot of form if possible

Comment: You are suspecting correctly - I've attached a screenshot. By using setAuthor I was hoping the author firstname/lastname would be updated when the article gets persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this (not tested) e.g  add new method `getAuthor` in your article controller  and call as follow

```
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return AppBundle\Entity\Author;
     */
    protected function getAuthor(EntityManager $em, Request $request){

        $email = $request->get('email');

        $author = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Author')->findOneByEmail($email);

        if(!$author){
            $author= new Author();
            $author->setLastName($email);
            $author->setFirstName($request->get('first_name'));
            $author->setLastName($request->get('last_name'));
            $em->persist($author);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $author;
    }


    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $article = new article();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\articleType', $article);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $author = $this->getAuthor($em,$request);

            $article = $form->getData();
            $article->setAuthor($author);
            $em->persist($article);
            $em->flush($article);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('article_show', array('id' => $article->getId()));

        }

        return $this->render('article/new.html.twig', array(
            'article' => $article,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to get it working based on your answer. I do have some questions that came out of it though that I hope you wouldn't mind answering. 1: What does sth stand for :)? 2: Why pass $em instead of getting a new one - memory efficiency? 3: Why pass request instead of the author directly - have I done something wrong by modifying your method to accept the author? 4: I had been told that if I persist a entity obtained by $em then it would simply update and not insert. this doesn't seem to be the case (it'd crash before moving persist to inside the else). was I told wrong?

Comment: 1) fixed 'sth' issue sorry for bad english, 2) yes its better to avoid extra calls /and create objects  3) your code is convoluted because author does exist when you call `$article->getAuthor()` in first place and the intention is not visible from code , your flow might be correct when you are updating and existing article not for new article.

Comment: 4) read this http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html , your concepts will be cleared and someone told you a lie

Comment: more about object persistence http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a bunch for the answer, clarification and reading material!

Comment: The other thing is to look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html , in case you have multiple author for one article

Answer (score 0):

Is the cascade part of the relation set properly (i.e. below)?

```
 /**
 * @OneToOne(... cascade={"persist"})
 */
```

Comment: It is, as far as I know. Thanks. I've included the article entity for reference.